# How to get Apache to bind correctly to a Virtual Host

Tags: apache, server, virtualhost, ubuntu-20.04

I have been working on setting up a website and I am using Apache on a Ubuntu 20.04 LS VM. I have the domain configured to point to the server and https is set up and working but whenever I go to the domain I get this view. [image: Apache Server View]

I have tried to get the domain to bind with the virtual host by using the server name tag but that is not working. This is my config file: [image: Apache Config File]
I am new to the world of running servers so sorry if this question is stupid:).
Let me know if I can add anything that would be helpful in this situation. This is the only website I am trying to host on this VM. Also, apache does not think that the folder shown in the image exists in the filesystem. I do not know if this would affect anything but to get my website files on the server I downloaded all the files into backpacking-project. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the reason why it was not working. It was because I uploaded a folder of my files to the server and apache did not recognize it in the filesystem. I uploaded the files separately that that worked.

Comment: That might be a solution but that was not your problem. You originally uploaded your files to **/var/www/backpacking-project/backpackingProject** but set the DocumentRoot to **/var/www/backpacking-project**. Make sure you understand how to configure Apache and not just blindly try things until magic happens.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the site issue, change DocumentRoot to

```
/var/www/backpacking-project/backpackingProject
```

Next, you should not allow Apache to display directory contents. Add these lines:

```
<Directory /var/www/backpacking-project/backpackingProject>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

[Apache Directory Listings](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DirectoryListings)

Next you should define the default page. Assuming the default page is index.html, add this line to the previous **Directory** section:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Change index.html to whatever you are using, e.g. for PHP use index.php or home.php, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing that and it appears that Apache is not listening to the document root. I tried changing it to what you suggested and nothing happened. To see if it was working I changed the document root to /var and nothing changed then either. Do you have any other suggestions? thanks.

Comment: @EvanB101 Did you restart Apache after making changes? **systemctl restart apache2**